# Correlation versus Correlation coefficient

Tags: probability, correlation

I have from my class  notes,

[image]

But when I search the web I can't find other sources that give this same formula for correlation. The [wikipedia article on correlation and dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) just shows the correlation coefficient. Would someone please explain the difference to me and why I can't find the $E[XY]$ definition of correlation on wikipedia?

Comment: I don't think anyone would define "correlation" between $X$ and $Y$ as $\operatorname{E}(XY)$ EXCEPT in a context where it's already been made clear that $X$ and $Y$ both have expected value $0$ and variance $1.\qquad$